Getting error - Unable to connect with Loki. Please check the server logs for more details
I have installed loki-stack using below values.yaml
loki:
auth_enabled: false
commonConfig:
path_prefix: /var/loki
replication_factor: 1
compactor:
apply_retention_interval: 1h
compaction_interval: 5m
retention_delete_worker_count: 500
retention_enabled: true
shared_store: s3
working_directory: /data/compactor
config:
schema_config:
configs:
- from: 2020-05-15
store: boltdb-shipper
object_store: s3
schema: v11
index:
period: 24h
prefix: loki_index_
  storage_config:
    aws:
      region: us-east-1
      bucketnames: grafana-loki-bucket
      s3forcepathstyle: false
    boltdb_shipper:
      shared_store: s3
      cache_ttl: 24h

serviceAccount:
create: true
name: loki-sa
annotations:
eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/grafana-loki-role"
write:
replicas: 2
read:
replicas: 1
promtail:
enabled: true
config:
server:
http_listen_port: 9080
grpc_listen_port: 0
positions:
filename: /promtail/positions.yaml  # Ensure this path is writable
clients:
- url: http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push
scrape_configs:
- job_name: kubernetes-pods
kubernetes_sd_configs:
- role: pod
pipeline_stages:
- docker: {}
- cri: {}
- json:
expressions:
severity: level
timestamp: ts
traceId: trace_id # Ensure you capture trace_id from logs
- replace:
source: traceId
target_label: traceID # Rename to the expected label
regex: "(.*)"
- drop:
source: traceId # Optionally drop the original field from logs
relabel_configs:
- source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
action: replace
target_label: namespace
- source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
action: replace
target_label: pod
- source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name]
action: replace
target_label: container
- source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_uid]
action: replace
target_label: pod_uid
- action: labelmap
regex: _meta_kubernetes_pod_label(.+)
extraVolumes:
  - name: promtail-positions 
    emptyDir: {}
extraVolumeMounts:
  - name: promtail-positions
    mountPath: /promtail

grafana:
enabled: true
I am able to view logs from pods, containers. I have installed tempo using
helm install tempo grafana/tempo
Able to view traces as well but not able to corelate the traces to logs. Trying to add derived fields but when clicked on Save & test getting --> "Unable to connect with Loki. Please check the server logs for more details". enter image description here
grafana svc has been exposed as a Load balancer and the loki datasource was added by default and there isn't an option change the loki URL.
checking the loki svc, grafana and loki pods but didn't find any issues
